# Is this sentence correct

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> My nose has been red cause of cold.

Above sentence is made by me. Is this sentence correct?

I am specifically wondering: Can we use "been" here? If we can, then why?

Comment: I'd say - my nose has **turned** red because of cold -

Comment: @Ale Is it wrong?

Comment: You can also say "my nose has become red due to cold"

Comment: I don't think is wrong but it sounds weird. Normally, when you want to express that something changes its state, you use **turn**.

Comment: _My nose has been red because of my cold._ (In sentences like these, I think _because_ is better than _cause_. Also, if you are talking about the "common cold," I'd say _my_ cold. If instead you are talking about the cold weather, use _the_ cold: _My nose has been red because of the cold._)

Comment: @J.R. I meant to say, can we use "been" here? If  we can then,why?

Comment: 1010: If you include information like that when you ask your question, then your questions won't get closed. Don't just ask, "Is this correct?" Instead, ask, "Is this correct? I have doubts about X," or "Is this okay? I don't know if X is the right way to say it," or something along those lines.

Comment: It is grammatically correct, but few native speakers would ever say it, because it is not idiomatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "been" can be used here; however, you ought to use "**be**cause" instead of "cause" and consider using "a" before "cold", or use the present perfect "have had". (Just note that "a" would imply that you still have a cold, while "have had" implies that your cold has since passed.)

> My nose has been red because I have had a cold.